# How to make a button move as the window size is adjusted? (PyQt4)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget

I know the 2nd line I commented out doesn't work, just a representation of what I was thinking. This would be running the whole time the program is, so it could adjust to size changes.

Is something like this possible?

```
import sys    
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("SciCalc")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('atom.png'))
        # self.setFixedSize(1000,800)
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Physics", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        btn.resize(100, 100)
        btn.resize(100, 100)
        # btn.move(width/2,height/2)
        self.show()


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that what you want is that the button stays in the middle of the window always, that you could do it by overwriting the `resizeEvent` method.

```
import sys    
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle("SciCalc")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('atom.png'))
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Physics", self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        self.btn.resize(100, 100)
        self.show()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.btn.move(self.rect().center()-self.btn.rect().center())
        QtGui.QMainWindow.resizeEvent(self, event)


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! Could you explain a little what your code does exactly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ceh358 
The resizeEvent method is called every time the widget resizes, so it is the right place to move the button. The calculation of how much is moving is subtracting the position of the center of the window and the center of the button so that it is in the middle.